# Chrome: Finding Blank Screens When Switching Back to Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, tabs, blank-screen

I'm using Chrome 36.0.1985.125 m on a 64-bit ASUS R500V laptop, running Windows 8.1.

Yesterday, I uninstalled Chrome, keeping my data, and re-installed it. I'd been having some problems with it, such as, if I had multiple tabs open, and I switched back to a tab I hadn't looked at for an hour or so, the page would be blank and take about 30-45 seconds to show whatever was actually on the page.

Unfortunately, neither yesterday's re-install of version 35.0.1916.153 m, nor today's update to the newest version, 36.0.1985.125 m, have solved that.

Has anybody heard of or experienced this issue, and more importantly, can anyone please help me find a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: [I've experienced this problem on the dev channel. It's a known, but hard to reproduce bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=384699)

Comment: I also have this issue, though it takes about 5 - 15 seconds for the page to show up.